# How to initialise Constructor of a Nested Class in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I am getting problems in initializing the nested class constructor.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
public:
class b
{
    public:
    b(char str[45])
        {
        cout<<str;
        }

    }title;
}document;

int main()
{
    document.title("Hello World"); //Error in this line
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> ```
> fun.cpp:21:30: error: no match for call to '(a::b)'
> ```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth fun.cpp:21:30: error: no match for call to '(a::b)'

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like:

```
class a
{
public:
    a():title(b("")) {}
    //....
};
```

This is because `title` is already a member of `a`, however you don't have a default constructor for it. Either write a default constructor or initialize it in the initialization list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either make your data member a pointer, or you can only call the data member's constructor from the initialiser list of the construtor of the class it is a member of (in this case, `a`)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
document.title("Hello World");
```

is not "initializing the nested class"; it's attempting to call `operator()` on the object.

The nested object is already initialised when you create `document`.  Except that it's not, because you've provided no default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So what do you have here:

```
class A {
  B title;
}
```

Without defining constructor for class A (as Luchian Grigore shown) title will be initialized as: `B title();`

You can work that around by:

```
A::A():title(B("Hello world"))

// Or by adding non parametric constructor:
class B {
  B(){

  }

  B( const char *str){

  }
}
```

Object title (in document) is already initialized and you cannot call constructor anymore, but you still may use syntax: `document.title(...)` by declaring and defining `operator()` but it won't be constructor anymore:

```
class B {
  const B& operator()(const char *str){
     cout << str;
     return *this;
  }
}
```