# How to call constructor of a nested class

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, constructor

First off, I'm not talking about questions like these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160267/how-to-initialise-constructor-of-a-nested-class-in-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844715/nested-class-and-constructor-calling-understanding)). I'm talking about a class that already has a constructor and is only nested by value, not by definition...if that makes any sense.

Currently, I have this methodology, which works, but uses `new` and is ugly IMO:

```
class A {
private:
    int value;

public:
    A(int _value);
};

class B {
private:
    A *a;
public:
    B(int _value);
};
```

The constructor of B:

```
B::B(int _value)
{
    a = new A(_value);
}
```

If I were to change `A *a;` to `A a`, how would I create a `B` such that `A`'s constructor is called in the same way?

I've tried:

```
B::B(int _value)
{
    a = A(_value);    // no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
    a = A::A(_value); // cannot call constructor ‘A::A’ directly
    a(_value);        // no match for call to ‘(A) (int&)’
    a.A(_value);      // invalid use of `A::A`
}
```

It doesn't seem possible without:

- using a pointer with `new`
- using some explicit `void A::init(_value)` (would need an additional constructor for `A` to take no arguments)
- extending class A (would require changing specific private members to protected and would mesh their "namespaces" in an unwanted manner)
- questionable use of `memcpy()` (`A temp(_value); memcpy(&a, &temp, sizeof (A));`)

Is this possible without resorting to the above methods?

Comment: Use a reference member and the constructor initializer list.

Comment: Is there any advantage a reference has over a value in this case? It seems like both get created upon creation of a `B`, and both have the same usage syntax and semantics.

Comment: No, I probably just got your question wrong.

Comment: @BradenBest If you don't have a reason to use a reference, don't. A plain `A a;` is most certainly what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use initialisation lists.

I.e. B constructor looks like

```
class B {
   ...

   A a;
};

B::B(int _value) : a(_value) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `a` is a pointer actually!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which is exactly what OP is trying to get rid of.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - He says we wants to change it from a pointer

Comment: @EdHeal Then complete your answer and show how to use a reference.

Comment: It works. I need to look up the `:` operator. Thanks!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why would he need a reference?

Comment: @BaummitAugen To keep semantics?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He does not want to keep the semantics, he wants good old value semantics of a plain "by value" member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what are you getting at? I want `a` to be a value (`A`), not a pointer (`A*`), not a reference (`A&`). This answer answers my question and gives me exactly what I asked for. Case closed.

Comment: @BradenBest Okey.